# Game of Life algorithm not working correctly

Tags: java

I have an assignment to write a game of life in Java. Here are the rules for the game if you are unfamiliar with them:
https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Life. I 'm following a guide with pseudocode that the teacher has given us. I'm at the last step where I have to write the actual algorithm that kills and spawns new life cells.

I feel like I've done everything right, but it's not working correctly and I don't know how I should proceed since I can't find any errors. I'm using a 2D Boolean array that I update once when I have calculated the new state of the board. The method for calculating neighbors and the other methods used is working correctly.

```java
public class Life {
LifeBoard brade, next;

Life(LifeBoard board) {
    this.brade = board;    //the actual board
    this.next = brade;     //copy of the board to use temporarily

    for (int a = 0; a < brade.length(); a++) { // Make all values false just to be shure)
        for (int b = 0; b < brade.length(); b++) {
            next.put(a, b, false);
        }
    }
}

void newGeneration() {
    for (int a = 0; a < brade.length(); a++) { 
        for (int b = 0; b < brade.length(); b++) {
            int grannar=brade.getGrannar(a, b);

            if(brade.get(a, b)) {                  //check is cell is alive
                if(grannar>=4) {
                    next.put(a, b, false);         //kills if neighbours >= 4
                } else {
                    if(grannar<=1) {
                        next.put(a, b, false);     //kills if neighbours <= 1
                    } else {
                        next.put(a, b, true);      //lets live
                    }
                }
            } else {                               //if cell is dead
                if(grannar==3) {
                    next.put(a, b, true);          //spawns if neighbours is 3
                } else {
                    next.put(a, b, false);         //keeps it dead 
                }
            }       
        }
    }

    brade = next;                                  //updates the array
    brade.increaseGeneration();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking someone to write the last step for you? Have you done the last step but there is a specific problem? If so, can you ask that specific problem? Try to make it easy for people to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create an actual copy of the object. brade, board and next all point to the same reference.

```
this.brade = board;    //the acctual board
this.next = brade;     //copy of the board to use temporarly
```

Edit:
You said you store the boardState in a 2d boolean array. Lets assume its called board and your LifeBoard class has a method called getBoard().

Create a new object instance for next and make a deep copy of this boolean array. For example use System.arraycopy(), but this only handels 1-dimensional arrays, so you need to loop over your 'outer' array.

Ps.:
If your boolean array has different dimensions your current code won't work either. Adjust your for loop's in this case.

Comment: How would i go about doing that then? Brade is a copy of board, and next is a coppy of brade, i dont see how i could do it differently.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how this could be done?